# cannot view GEOGRAPHY in SSMS (spatial result tab)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, spatial

This:

```
DECLARE @g GEOMETRY

SET @g = GEOMETRY::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-3.19133 57.12592, -3.20621 57.12339, -3.24347 57.11936, -3.28312 57.10994, -3.34619 57.10951, -3.36079 57.11114, -3.3713 57.11414, -3.31958 57.17965, -3.2243 57.22291, -3.22278 57.22303, -3.21168 57.22427, -3.20742 57.22845, -3.16721 57.27598, -3.15209 57.29011, -3.14448 57.29477, -3.14382 57.29464, -3.03228 57.28542, -3.01872 57.28257, -3.01236 57.2823, -2.99083 57.2772, -2.99133 57.24862, -2.9881 57.24493, -2.97908 57.22876, -2.9676 57.22416, -2.96754 57.22275, -2.98005 57.20513, -2.97461 57.20236, -2.96718 57.20133, -2.96686 57.20082, -2.95002 57.18476, -2.94752 57.17462, -2.95713 57.17252, -2.97368 57.16715, -2.98438 57.15701, -2.98449 57.15695, -2.98529 57.15668, -3.0318 57.14936, -3.06189 57.12386, -3.07636 57.12476, -3.07786 57.12499, -3.09228 57.12804, -3.12085 57.13076, -3.12753 57.12961, -3.19133 57.12592))', 4326);

SELECT @g
```

allows me to view the result in SSMS (spatial result tab). However, when I use GEOGRAPHY instead:

```
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY

SET @g = GEOGRAPHY::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-3.19133 57.12592, -3.20621 57.12339, -3.24347 57.11936, -3.28312 57.10994, -3.34619 57.10951, -3.36079 57.11114, -3.3713 57.11414, -3.31958 57.17965, -3.2243 57.22291, -3.22278 57.22303, -3.21168 57.22427, -3.20742 57.22845, -3.16721 57.27598, -3.15209 57.29011, -3.14448 57.29477, -3.14382 57.29464, -3.03228 57.28542, -3.01872 57.28257, -3.01236 57.2823, -2.99083 57.2772, -2.99133 57.24862, -2.9881 57.24493, -2.97908 57.22876, -2.9676 57.22416, -2.96754 57.22275, -2.98005 57.20513, -2.97461 57.20236, -2.96718 57.20133, -2.96686 57.20082, -2.95002 57.18476, -2.94752 57.17462, -2.95713 57.17252, -2.97368 57.16715, -2.98438 57.15701, -2.98449 57.15695, -2.98529 57.15668, -3.0318 57.14936, -3.06189 57.12386, -3.07636 57.12476, -3.07786 57.12499, -3.09228 57.12804, -3.12085 57.13076, -3.12753 57.12961, -3.19133 57.12592))', 4326);

SELECT @g
```

I cannot view the result in SSMS (spatial result tab). Is this normal behavior, or is there something wrong with my syntax, which does not produce any errors.

PS:

It did not work because of [this](http://danielwertheim.se/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position/).

Comment: So what happens then? The spatial results tab loads but you don't see anything? It doesn't display at all? Something else?

Comment: About the Spatial results tab...This window is not available if your query results do not contain spatial data or **if you specify that your results are returned as text**.  [View Spatial Data in Object Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/view-spatial-data-in-object-explorer?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not view my Geography polygon because the points used the clockwise order! See [this](http://danielwertheim.se/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position-no/) link.

Comment: As a tip for the future, there's a ReorientObject method in SQL 2012+ that will do exactly that. As a heuristic, I use "is the area greater than a hemisphere?". If it is, I re-orient it since that's almost certainly not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not "normal" behavior. You should be able to view both Geography and Geometry results in the Spatial Results tab.  I tried both your queries in my local SSMS 2012 and they work fine.

Can you make sure that in your query window that you right-click and have "Results To -> Grid" selected?

Comment: did what you suggested - still no luck )-:

Comment: Actually, my polygon cannot work. I found this: http://danielwertheim.se/2012/12/03/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position-no/  ... I changed the order of the points and it works. Not sure how it could have worked for you!

Comment: I misunderstood your question as saying that the Spatial Results tab was missing altogether, which will happen if you're not in grid mode.   Your second query actually produces a Spatial Results tab, but there is no polygon in it now that I double check it.

Comment: The link above is incorrect. The correct is: http://danielwertheim.se/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position-no/